# Flex child grows over container when parent uses flex and elements have no content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this strange behavior I cannot explain myself.

```css
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fc > article {
  flex: 1 1 auto;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.fc > article > .p1 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
}

.fc > article > .p2 {
    flex: 1 1 75%;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="fc">
  <article>
    <p class="p1">Hello world</p>
    <p class="p2">
    Something texty
    </p>
  </article>
  
  <article>
    <p class="p1"></p>
    <p class="p2">
    Something texty
    </p>
  </article>
  
  <article>
    <p class="p1">Hello World 3</p>
    <p class="p2">
    Something texty
    </p>
  </article>
</div>
```

So it's basicly a wrapper div using flex and articles inside which are flex-containers themself. To keep it simple, i removed the padding & margin from the p (in the original code these are other elements anyway)

The problem starts when there is no text inside the first p. Somehow the second p overflows the article.

[image: overflow of p in article]

Here in stackoverflow snipped I only get the effect using "Inspect Element" from the Browser. If you save the code in an html file and open it in the browser, you will get the effect.

A possible fix is to use `px/rem` instead of `%` as `flex-basis` but I would like to have % here.

I can also fix this problem using a `&nbsp;` inside the `p` but this seems more like a hacky solution than a real one.

Comment: I don't see this on Chrome or firefox but it's clear that the culprit is the percentage value that has no reference but the content itself

Comment: *If you save the code in an html file and open it in the browser, you will get the effect.* Are you including the doctype on the top?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tested it with chrome and indeed it doesn't seem to be a problem there. I use firefox. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis it states that I can use a percentage as `flex-basis` to function as a percentage of the parents main size

Comment: yes and the parent doesn't have a size defined, so its size will be based on it's content then the percentage will get resolved. A kind of complex cycle that's wht I said there is no reference since the size is not explicitely defined

Answer (score 0):

If you'll define at least a min-height for the second p, it should solve the issue.

```
.fc > article > .p1 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    min-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: while this helps with the overflow problem, the output is different from what i expect. i expect the first p to be 25% of the whole article and the second one to fill the remaining 75%

Comment: Then I'm afraid the best solution would be using &nbsp; inside that p1.